# iOS html5 css3 button click style

Tags: ios, html, css

I write my application on HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript. For my button I create style (all work fine in browser), but when I start my application on iPad my active effect override standart iOS click effect.
How I can override this standart effect?

My style :

```
<style type="text/css">    
.button {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
background: #f78d1d;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #faa51a,  #f47a20);
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#faa51a', endColorstr='#f47a20');
}

.button:ACTIVE {
background: #f47c20;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f88e11), to(#f06015) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f88e11, #f06015);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f88e11', endColorstr='#f06015' );
}
```

My Button:

```
<a href="#" class="button"></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your problem I believe is very simple.

Add this following CSS code to your button or body tag (to affect the entire document).

```
body { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

This will remove default styles for buttons that iOS places onto certain UI elements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem use the button tag and it seems to override.

```
<button class="button"><a href="#go">Link</a></button>
```